# Online payment system for Subscription embedded in website

Tags: web-services, online-payment

I'm developing a web site and I want to provide user a subscription service. I wonder if there is an online payment service which I can embed into my website and capable of managing recurring payment?

Also, security of the system to registered users is of high importance.

Thank you for your suggestions!
Paul

Comment: This question misses a lot of essential information: what is the website build with, what are you willing to pay, what research have you done already? Also, *security of the system to registered users is of high importance* is not really saying much. Of course security around payment is important, why are you adding it? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.